# Programmatically Left Justify a number in an Excel document

Tags: vb.net, excel, export-to-excel

How do I left justify my columns in Excel programmatically in VB? I have a VB program that is writing an excel file based off of certain information.  I have tried using:

```
oSheet.Columns.HorizontalAlignment.Left()
```

This works against columns with text.  I have multiple columns that are strictly numbers.  This function will not work against columns with Numeric Cells.

Below is the MissingMemberException I keep getting:

```
Public member 'Left' on type 'Integer' not found.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Range.HorizontalAlignment is a property that requires an integer constant.  Left is xlLeft.  xlLeft evaluates to -4131.  xlDistributed is -4117, xlRight is -4152, xlCenter is -4108, and xlJustify is -4130.

Answer (score 0):

HorizontalAlignment should work for both text and numbers. You should specify the value for the alignment though since it is a property.

Answer (score 0):

Although the @Banjoe answer will work, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlhalign.aspx) specifies the following valid constants for HorizontalAlignment property:

```
xlHAlignCenter
xlHAlignCenterAcrossSelection
xlHAlignDistributed
xlHAlignFill
xlHAlignGeneral
xlHAlignJustify
xlHAlignLeft
xlHAlignRight
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following, and it worked great for me:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
objExcel.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Some data"
objExcel.Cells(1, 2).Value = "More data"
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objExcel.Columns(2).Select
objExcel.Selection.EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = 2
```